# Call method of another class (for example via singleton class)?

Tags: iphone, ios, methods, uiviewcontroller

I used [this](http://iphone.galloway.me.uk/iphone-sdktutorials/singleton-classes/) simple tutorial to create my singleton class. Everything works fine. One thing it doesn't say in the tutorial, how to create methods in that class, so I can access them from other classes (e.g. other ViewControllers or the AppDelegate.)

How can I do it?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will define methods just like you do in any other Objective-C file. Add a definition to the header for public methods and then implement them in the implementation (.m) file.

```
#import <foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyManager : NSObject {
    NSString *someProperty;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *someProperty;

+ (id)sharedManager;

//Add instance methods for your singleton here
- (void)someSingletonMethod;

@end
```

Usage:

```
[[MyManager sharedManager] someSingletonMethod];
```

Answer (score 1):

singleton .h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 @interface SingleTon : NSObject
{
  NSString *sum;

}

+(SingleTon *) createSingleTon;
-(NSString *) sumOfTwoNumbers:(NSString *) numOne :(NSString *)numTwo;
@end
```

singleton .m file

```
#import "SingleTon.h"

@implementation SingleTon

+(SingleTon *) createSingleTon
{
    static SingleTon *single= nil;
    if (single == nil) {

        single = [[SingleTon alloc] init];
    }
    return single;
}

-(NSString *) sumOfTwoNumbers:(NSString *) numOne :(NSString *)numTwo
{
    sum =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[numOne intValue] + [numTwo intValue]];
    return sum;
}

@end
```

viecontroller.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SingleTon.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    SingleTon *sing;
    IBOutlet UITextField *one,*two,*sum;
}
-(IBAction)sum:(id)sender;
@end
```

viecontroller.m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    sing = [SingleTon createSingleTon];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(IBAction)sum:(id)sender
{
    sum.text = [sing sumOfTwoNumbers:one.text :two.text];

}
@end
```

o/p[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make one class method for your first class like this. also declare it in .h file as well.

```
+(FFMainVC *)sharedSingleton
{
    static FFMainVC *instance = nil;

    if(instance == nil)
        instance = [[FFMainVC alloc]init];

    return instance;
}
// write your method that you wants to access from other class. also declare this in .h as well

-(void)showCartView
{ 
       // Your Code
}  
// make call of your method from second class like this
[[FFMainVC sharedSingleton]showCartView];
```